# Duplicate values for x-frame-options

Tags: security, x-frame-options, clickjacking

I'm setting x-frame-options on the pages of my website but due to some nested logic, on some pages I see duplicate values like:

```
X-FRAME-OPTIONS:SAMEORIGIN,SAMEORIGIN
```

instead of:

```
X-FRAME-OPTIONS:SAMEORIGIN
```

Is it okay to have duplicate values assigned to X-FRAME-OPTIONS and will it pick the first value that is assigned and ignore the rest?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This should be fine on most modern browsers. [Apparently](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/advisories/mfsa2012-51/), there was an issue where a duplicated value in the `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` header would cause the header to be ignored entirely, but this has been fixed in Firefox > 14. I imagine that this issue, if it ever existed in the first place, has been similarly fixed in Chrome and Edge as well.

Answer (score 3):

I am researching the same thing, as we have added X-FRAME-OPTIONS but it is ALSO added by Html.AntiForgeryToken().

I have not found a conclusive answer to the duplicates, though it does seem that if they ARE the same it is not a problem.  The issue does remain, however, if there are [conflicting multiple entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44137501/what-browsers-are-vulnerable-for-multiple-x-frame-options) since they can be mutually exclusive.  I did find a [solution](https://www.georgephillipson.com/blog/asp-net/duplicate-x-frame-options-sameorigin/) that worked for me, specifically the SuppressXFrameOptionsHeadersAttribute.